# I want use set to remove duplicate element and keep the order when they insert

Tags: c++, stl, set

I want use set to remove duplicate elements and keep their order by the same time. So I try to change the compare parameter to let they sort with the order they are inserted.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <class T>
struct compare
{
    bool operator() (T x, T y) 
    {
        return true;
    }
};

void main()
{
    set<int,compare<int>> one;

    one.insert(5);
    one.insert(3);
    one.insert(9);
    one.insert(1);
    one.insert(5);
    one.insert(5);
}
```

The expression from the IDE is :invaild operator <

Comment: A `std::set` already orders its items and does not contain duplicates.  There is no need for you to "help" the set out on any of these issues.  So I guess a `set` is not the container you should be using.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use std::set? *What are you trying to do?*

Comment: I know it has no duplicates inside.I just want all element being placed just the order that they are inserted.

Comment: For example,"5,3,6,7,1" has been inserted in one set one by one and I want them still keep the same order,"5,3,6,7,1", after being inserted into that set.

Comment: `std::set` needs a simple weak ordering. Order of insertion doesn't satisfy that. Your comparator certainly doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set` relies on the comparator to maintain strict weak ordering and ensure each value is unique. You can't have a `std::set` sort in the order they are inserted.

One possible solution is to have two containers, a `std::set` to contain the unique elements and a `std::vector` index to keep the order they were inserted. The vector could perhaps contain iterators into the set.

It might be convenient to encapsulate the two containers in your own class with its own iterator. Here is a bare-bones implementation:

```
class MySetIterator {
  std::vector<std::set<int>::iterator>::iterator pos;
public:
  MySetIterator(std::vector<std::set<int>::iterator>::iterator pos) : pos(pos) {}
  int operator*() { return **pos; }
  MySetIterator& operator++() { ++pos; return *this; }
  bool operator!=(const MySetIterator& rhs) { return pos != rhs.pos; }    
};

class MySet {
 std::set<int> vals;
 std::vector<std::set<int>::iterator> order;
public:
  void insert(int val) { 
    auto ret = vals.insert(val);
    if (ret.second)
      order.push_back(ret.first);
  }
  MySetIterator begin() { return {order.begin()}; }
  MySetIterator end() { return {order.end()}; }    
};

int main() {
  MySet my_set;

  my_set.insert(5);
  my_set.insert(3);
  my_set.insert(9);
  my_set.insert(1);
  my_set.insert(5);
  my_set.insert(5);
  for (int val : my_set)
      std::cout << val << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Other possible solution is to use boost::multi_index.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>

namespace boost_mi = boost::multi_index;

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    int,
    boost_mi::indexed_by<
        boost_mi::random_access<>, // preserves insertion order
        boost_mi::ordered_unique<boost_mi::identity<int> > // removes duplicates
    >
> MySet;

int main()
{
    MySet my_set;

    my_set.push_back(5);
    my_set.push_back(3);
    my_set.push_back(9);
    my_set.push_back(1);
    my_set.push_back(5);
    my_set.push_back(5);

    for (auto val : my_set) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```